# Window's Files not appearing in Ubuntu.

Tags: windows, nautilus

I'm trying to delete old system files in Windows 7, I switched into Ubuntu to delete the files there but now I can't see the files. They are on my D: drive and I can see all of the files on my C: drive, but not the D.  I know that ubuntu doesn't enumerate the drives but I have located the drives in Ubuntu and am still having trouble accessing the files. I have tried using ctrl + H but the files still do not show up.

Comment: If your running WUBI, you won't be able to access Windows' files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the opposite problem. I installed ubuntu on my C: drive and only the D: is listed. C: is missing.

My guess is that the partition where you installed ubuntu is never listed.

Take a look at the **/host** folder and your files may be there.

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: From your desktop, click the **Computer** icon. 

Then click on **File System**. 

You will see all linux folders. The folder **host** will be there.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm a newbie and mine may be a "newbie" method. I don't know wheteher there is another (easier) way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the partition is correctly mount.

Do those files and folders start with a dot ".", they are by default hidden, you'll have to  use `ls -la` to display those (or Ctrl+h to show in nautilus).

Run `findmnt` or `mount | column -t`, paste the output.

Also, is partition D encrypted (EFS)?

Comment: None of the files start with "." I double checked, it is properly mounted.

Comment: I updated the answer.